# Laravel hasOneThrough Relationship In Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, has-one-through

Suppose I have a database schema as follows:

```
Department -> id | department_name
Employee -> id | department_id | name
Attendance -> id | employee_id | timestamp
```

I am able to retrieve all attendances from a department using `hasManyThrough` relationship as follows from the `Department` Model:

```
public function attendance() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(EmployeeAttendance::class, Employee::class, 'department_id', 'employee_id', 'id', 'id');
}
```

However, I am trying to do the reverse, i.e retrieve the department of an employee from the attendance model. I have tried to use the `hasOneThrough` relationship but I have not been able to get it. I have reviewed the documentation as well as other tutorials on the same. Any help on how I could do so via relationship in the `Attendance` model will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eager load nested relationships, you can see more about them in the the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

```
Attendance::with('employee.department')->find($id);
```

If you are trying to build a relationship between attendance and department you would want to do something like this:
In Attendance Model:

```
public function employee()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class);
}
```

In Employee Model:

```
public function department()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
}
```

Comment: Why do you use many to many relationship in your answer?